# How does the "BiasAdjust" term in Match() function from Matching R package work?

Tags: experiment-design, causality, matching

In the `Match()` function in the Matching R package, it takes in inputs like:

```
Match(Y=NULL, Tr, X, Z = X, V = rep(1, length(Y)), estimand = "ATT", M = 1,
BiasAdjust = FALSE, exact = NULL, caliper = NULL, replace=TRUE, ties=TRUE, ...)
```

I noticed that many of my estimates are much more correct in simulations when I set `BiasAdjust = TRUE`. I tried to look in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf), their [vignette](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v042i07/v42i07.pdf), and even the [function](https://rdrr.io/cran/Matching/src/R/Matching.R) itself, but am failing to understand how it really works.

Apparently it regresses the outcomes on the covariates to improve matching estimates. Does anyone have an idea how this fits into the whole framework of propensity score matching? Thanks.

Comment: This adjustment is explained in [Abadie and Imbens (2002)](https://www.nber.org/papers/t0283.pdf).

Comment: You can also try emailing the package authors.